# How to get rid of smw?

Tags: windows-8.1

Every time I open the windows 8.1, the message pops up:
"c:\users\Local\Temps\smw_update_both.exe
The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable."

It seems my ant-malware program blocked smw updating or something. How can I stop this smw's activity?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question as written is unclear and difficult for us to understand. We can answer your question better if you edit it to improve spelling, grammar, and formatting or to add additional information about the specific issue at hand. For more information on how to ask a good question, see the [help center](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw on the [internet](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=smw_update_both.exe), there's a chance it's a malware.

To try and stop it, you can:

- Try to delete the file. If it failed, I'll guess it's open somewhere. So lets try to see if it's starting on startup or a service.

  - Open msconfig (from the Run), go to startup tab - and look there if the exe exist. If so - disable it.
  - If it's not there, you can check if it's a windows service. You can run this command `tasklist /svc /fi "IMAGENAME eq spoolsv.exe"` from command line (replace spoolsv.exe with your exe name, you can use wildcard), and it will search and show you if there's a service running with this exe.
- You can also use [procexp](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and search the exe name, to who uses the file, and what's he's doing.

Hope it helps somehow